# What is use of middleware in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm not clear with the concept of middleware in Laravel. What does laravel middleware do? Please provide an example if possible.

Comment: Read the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware its all there with example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Middleware is something that is placed between two requests.

Suppose that you need to make sure that when user access to a specific group of routes he/she is authenticated.

There are two option:

1. Add in every controller the code to check if user is logged in ( in this example we do not consider a parent controller )
2. Use a middleware

In the first case you should write in each controller the same code.

With the middleware you have a piece of code that you can re-use in multiple section of your application.

Let's suppose that we want to create a Middleware that need to check if the user is logged in:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class UserIsLoggedIn
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!auth()->user()) {
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Now with this code we can check our user where we need.
First of all since this is a custom middleware you need to register it in the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file in the $`routeMiddleware` property:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    // ...
    'isLoggedIn => \App\Http\Middleware\UserIsLoggedIn::class,
];
```

Let's assume that you have a group of routes that need to check the user is logged in:

```
Route::get('admin/profile', function () {
    //
})->middleware('isLoggedIn');
```

Now all the routes in this group will check if the user is logged otherwise he will be redirect to home.

Now assume that you have another controller that need to make sure that the user is logged in, now you can re-use the middleware to do that:

```
class MyController extend Controller {
    function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('isLoggedIn');
    }
}
```

So middleware help you to organize the login and re-use pieces of code for specific tasks.

Laravel has a lot of documentation about middleware that you can [find here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware)